# Should I use parenthesis in postfix `if` syntax?

Tags: perl

Are there any benefits to use parenthesis in postfix `if` statement? like:

```
return 1 if ($self->found());
```

One of my workmate stick to use parenthesis and It's not common for me.  I would appreciate if someone point out differences.

Following is output from `perl -MO=Deparse`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $found = 1;

print "FOUND\n" if $found;
print "FOUND\n" if ($found);

__END__
test.pl syntax OK
use strict;
my $found = 1;
print "FOUND\n" if $found;
print "FOUND\n" if $found;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parens are never needed around the condition in the `if` statement modifier, so consistency and playing-it-safe aren't factors. (Same goes for the other statement modifiers.)

I don't see any advantage to using them. In fact, I find them a bit jarring.

I believe most experienced Perl programmers don't use them, to the point that it's a fair indicator of "newbieness".

Answer (score 4):

It's mainly a matter of style.  There's no requirement to use parens around the entire conditional expression and it has no effect on the way the code behaves, so decide for yourself what standard you want to use.  Personally, I don't, and my impression is that most Perl programmers don't either, but that could just be selection bias.

I will note, though, that any time I start wanting to use parens within the conditional expression, that's a pretty good sign that it shouldn't be in a postfix clause, so then I put parens around the whole thing and change it to the `if (...) {...}` form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Perl Best Practices](https://books.google.no/books/about/Perl_Best_Practices.html?id=gJf9tI2mytIC&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y), you should only `postfix if` for control of flow (`break`, `next`, `last`). When you use `postfix if` you should probably have easy enough if-statements to not need parenthesis.

For `If blocks` I think the best practice is to use parenthesis.

Comment: Re "For If blocks I think the best practice is to use parenthesis", For `if (EXPR) BLOCK`, you have to use parens.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the parentheses because more often than not I guess wrong on how many statements I need to be conditional. Then I have to rewrite the line to become a proper `if (condition) { BLOCK }`. Having the parentheses already there make this slightly easier.

There's also the mental/readability benefit of having *all if statements look the same*.

Comment: Re "There's also the mental/readability benefit of having all if statements look the same.", Are you saying you always use the statement form (`if (EXPR) BLOCK`)?

Comment: @ikegami Mostly. But sometimes I get inconsistent with my own preferences. It even happens that my preferences change over time :-)